# Ruby remove words ending with '.'

Tags: python, ruby

I'm looking to remove all middle initials in a series of names. I found out I could do this with Python so figured I would try it inRruby. In Python I could use the endswith command to remove all of the middle initials in a *csv file* because they were the only items that ended in a '.'

example

```
steve A. walkins

michael todd

Angel, Blair C.
```

Not all names follow a set pattern, but all middle initials do. So to teach myself some ruby trying to find out the equivilent command and usage to the endswith function I could do in python.

My sample Python code that worked for this was.

```
 print ' '.join(i for i in name.split(' ') if not i.endswith('.'))
```

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F

Comment: When asking questions, please take a little time to proofread your question and set capitaliasation and markup right. This makes it easier for others to understand and answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to pretend my answer is better than one suggested by Ivaylo Strandjev, but in case you want a oneliner which is a ‘translation’ of your python code to ruby:

```
name.split.select{|t| !t.end_with?('.')}.join(' ')
```

or, even clearer (thanks to @ŁukaszNiemier)

```
name.split.reject{|t| t.end_with?('.')}.join(' ')
```

Comment: +1 Actually your answer **is** better :) I like the use of `join` instead of my ugly `inject`.

Comment: Thanks this got my script working very much appreciated you guys!

Comment: @LegenWaitforitDary: Would you mark the answer as corrent than, so that other visitors may gain a benefit of qa-solved pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby there is a method `end_with?`.

Here is some example ruby code to do what you want:

```
def remove_initial name
   names = name.split
   names.select{|t| !t.end_with?(".")}.inject{|a,b| a + " " + b}
end
```

And a short exaplanation:

The first line `name.split` simply splits the name using default whitespace separator.

`names.select{|t| !t.end_with?(".")}` will filter only the names that do not end with a `.`, and then `inject{|a,b| a + " " + b}` will accumulate the remaining names adding a single whitepace between them.